# Convergence of the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a+\frac{1}{k})^{k}$ , a ≥ 0

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(a+\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k}
, a ≥ 0
$$
I have to determine whether it converges or not.

I came to a solution so far, that the series must converge for a < 1 and diverges for a > 1.

However, I'm wondering if this really is the solution to this series or if there is a concrete answer where you can conclude that the series must converge/diverge for every a≥0, that I'm not seeing.

Comment: Series $\sum a_k$ converges if $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}|a_k|^{\frac{1}{k}} <1$ and diverges if the limit is $>1$. Can you apply this to your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As OP and @Yathiraj Sharma's comment point out, the series converges for $a \in [0,1)$ and diverges for $a \in (1,+\infty)$. Remains the case where $a=1$.

We have :
$$(1+1/k)^k = \exp(k\ln(1+1/k)) \to \exp(1) = e \neq 0$$
Therefore the series diverges for $a=1$

Comment: That's what i was thinking aswell. Thanks for your input/clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Using [root test](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/roottest.aspx), the given series converges if
\begin{align*}
&\lim_{k\to \infty} \left \{ \left ( a+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k\right \}^{\frac1k}<1\\
\implies &\lim_{k\to \infty} \left ( a+\frac{1}{k}\right)<1\\
\implies &a<1
\end{align*}
Similarly, it diverges if $a>1$.

Now, we need to deal with the final case of $a=1$. But, this is the famous
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k\to \infty} \left ( 1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=e
\end{align*}
which means the terms of the sum don't go to $0$ as $k$ goes to infinity.

So, the series converges when $a<1$ and diverges when $a\geq1$.

Does that help?

Comment: Are you sure it converges when $a=1$? The terms do not even tend to zero.

Comment: @Gary Thanks for pointing that out. Somehow, I lost my mind when I was typing the answer. I did the correction. Is it okay now?

Comment: Yes, it is correct now.

Comment: @Gary thanks again